# Eclipse Juno Keyboard shortcut build project

Tags: eclipse

I am running eclipse Juno (4.2.1) on OpenSuSE 11.4.

I assigned the shortcut `ctrl+b` to the action "build project" having the context "in windows".

When editing code in the C/C++ Editor, the shortcut doesn't have any effect, the project will not be built.

This worked perfectly in previous versions of eclipse.

Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this in Juno as well.  I've read that it is a bug that was introduced.  It's apparently described here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383497

...which seems to indicate that 4.2.2 will have a fix.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial workaround, you can associate "make target" dialogue with the ctrl+b shortcut. That's what I did.